# Nested variables that rely on one another

Tags: bash, variable, variable-substitution

I'm trying to automate WireGuard on my OpenWrt router but I'm having some issues with nested variables when it comes to creating my configuration file. Below are the variables I have set:

```
export LAN="guest"
export interface="10.0.5"
export DDNS="my-ddns.no-ip.com"
export WG_${LAN}_server_port="51820"
export WG_${LAN}_server_IP="10.0.5.1/24"
export WG_${LAN}_server_firewall_zone="${LAN}"
```

The last three variables are expanded to:

```
export WG_guest_server_port="51820"
export WG_guest_server_IP="10.0.5.1/24"
export WG_guest_server_firewall_zone="guest"
```

In the conf file I'm trying to define the **endpoint** parameter by expanding the variables

```
cat <<EOF > "/etc/wireguard/peer.conf"
Endpoint = ${DDNS}:${WG_${LAN}_server_port}
EOF
```

Unfortunately I'm getting **-ash: syntax error: bad substitution**

How do call up a variable that also contains a variable? I need to expand the $LAN variable whilst expanding the $WG_guest_server_port which also relies on the first $LAN variable.

N.B. Ash is a light version of Bash and usually ships with Busybox. I'm writing a script for the OpenWrt community Wiki and so ash (Busybox) is included with all versions of OpenWrt.

Comment: Note: you tagged `bash` but the error is from `ash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${WG_${LAN}_server_port}` doesn't work in any shell I know. In Ksh, Bash or Zsh, you'd have ways of doing indirect references, i.e. referencing a variable named in another.

But you said OpenWrt and ash, so you probably only have the bare POSIX features.

In that case, you probably need to fall back to `eval`, as ugly as it is.

You could do something like this to first load the contents of `WG_guest_server_port` indirectly to another variable, and then use that in the here-doc:

```
eval "serverport=\${WG_${LAN}_server_port}"
cat <<EOF > "/etc/wireguard/peer.conf"
Endpoint = ${DDNS}:${serverport}
EOF
```

Note that that means the contents `${LAN}` become part of a line of *code*. A malicious user could form a special value that would cause the script to run arbitrary commands. So don't do that if `$LAN` contains untrusted data.